# Как выводить при использовании toFixed не нули, а конкретные числа, если после запятой много нулей?

Tags: javascript, числа, fixed

Сейчас есть числа, которые округляются до toFixed(3), но если оно меньше 0.001, до 8 знаков.
Но все равно бывает, что выводится 0.00000000, т.к. последующие числа идут далее.
Можно ли сделать какой-то адаптивный toFixed в зависимости от количества нулей после запятой?
Отображать мне 13.23414351534526 неинтересно (округляю их до 13.234), но вот в случае 0.00000000134252641 хотелось бы видеть число до первых двух чисел, отличающихся от нуля (0.0000000013)...
Благодарю.
Спрашиваю, т.к. не хотелось бы делать кучу if, но если нет способа иного, сделаю так...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще говоря из-за особенностей хранения чисел с плавающей точкой задача не имеет корректного решения для чисел типа `2.05`, которое хранится как `2.04999999999`

Ну и код просто откусывает две первых значащих цифры, а не округляет. Если нужно именно округление, т.е. из `2.549` получить `2.55`, то нужно будет код переписать

```js
function adaptiveFixed(num, needNonZero) {
  let res = Math.trunc(num);
  let frac = Math.abs(num - res);
  if (frac === 0)
    return res;
  res += '.';
  let numNonZero = 0;
  while (frac !== 0 && numNonZero < needNonZero) {
    frac *= 10;
    const cur = Math.floor(frac);
    res += cur;
    frac -= cur;
    if (cur !== 0)
      numNonZero++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(adaptiveFixed(-2.5, 2));
console.log(adaptiveFixed(2.52345, 2));
console.log(adaptiveFixed(2.05, 2));
console.log(adaptiveFixed(2.000000000000052345, 2));
```

Comment: Нет. Речь не про округление, а про фикс.
Проблема в том, что есть числа, где нынешний вариант норм, но есть числа, где все равно получается 0.00000000 из-за того, что лишь далее идут числа. Вот и хочу сделать так, чтоб отображалось 2 числа, идущих далее.

Comment: @DenisSkripnik Вы запускали мой код?

Comment: А всё. Разобрался. Благодарю.